# Avoid redundancy of HTML entities in .NET framework

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have to store various [HTML named character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references) for the following purposes:

1. Escaping special characters `myStringBuilder.Replace("À", WebHelper.Agrave)`
2. Insert spaces in legacy reports `ReportButtons.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(WebHelper.Space))`

This is the way I used to store until now:

```
public static class WebHelper
{
    #region [ Fields ]

    public const string Agrave = "&Agrave;";

    public const string Space = "&nbsp;";

    #endregion
}
```

Is this Single-Generic-Helper-Class the best way to solve this problem? Should all my programs reference it?

Comment: Calling `&nbsp;` just “space” is confusing. It's not the normal space, it's a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the [Server.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function?

Here is a brief description of what it does:

> Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80
>   is converted to &#<number>, where <number> is the ASCII character
>   value.

It also converts common ascii characters such as <, >, &, and " to their html character references.